# Functions in Powershell - can they be called within a string?

Tags: function, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, string-concatenation

I'm loving how functions can vastly reduce the busywork within Powershell scripts, and they've saved me a ton of redundant coding. But I'm now having issues invoking a declared function within a Powershell string (as part of a concatenated string using '+' sign) and wondering if there is a trick to doing this. Some sample code:

```
#this function takes input and either returns the input as the value, or returns 
placeholder text as the value

function val ($valinput)
{ if ($valinput)
   {return $valinput}
   else
   {$valinput = "No Results!"; return $valinput}
}
```

If I call the function at the beginning of the line or by itself:

```
val("yo!")
```

It runs fine. But if I attempt to concatenate it as part of a string, for example:

```
"The results of the tests are: " + val($results)
```

Powershell seems to have problems executing the function there, and I
get **'You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of
the '+' operator.'** and **'Unexpected token 'val' in expression or
statement.'** errors.

Is there a way to properly call a function within the concatenated string? I know I can push the results of the function to another variable and concatenate the resulting variable as part of the string, but that would be cumbersome to do that each and every time I call this function. Thanks in advance...!

Comment: Think I may have stumbled across an old trick:

"The results of the tests are: " + $(val($results))

seems to work. I'll leave this open for any to confirm this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Wrap the command/function call in a subexpression inside an expandable string:

```
"The results of the test are: $(val "yo!")"
```

---

Also worth pointing out, the syntax for command invocation in PowerShell doesn't require parentheses. I would discourage using parentheses like you do in the example altogether, since you'll end up in situations where consecutive arguments are being treated as one:

```
function val ($inputOne,$inputTwo)
{
    "One: $inputOne"
    "Two: $inputTwo"
}
```

Now, using C#-like syntax, you'd do:

```
val("first","second")
```

but find that the output becomes:

```
One: first second
Two:
```

because the PowerShell parser sees the nested expression `("first","second")` and treats it as a single argument.

The correct syntax for positional parameter arguments would be:

```
val "first" "second"
```

Comment: Important point about the difference in calling syntax between Powershell functions and functions in, say, Java.  A lot of us grew up with parentheses, and we find ourselves unconsciously drifting back into them.

Comment: Using a mix of Powershell and .net functions doesn't help either to know what to use when. That tripped me up so many times it isn't funny anymore. *(perhaps I should read a manual)*

Comment: @WalterMitty Perhaps it becomes easier if you think of PowerShell more as a shell (like bash, CMD, ...) and less as a programming language.